SAS_Recursive Function to Estimate parameter
I am trying to use SAS to estimate a parameter in a time-series AR function, with the key equation and dataset details below:
X_t = beta*X_t-1 + (1-beta)*a_t

In this AR equation, I have the initial value X0 as 2, and the time-series value of a are all known, so my data looks like this:



Date
a_t




t1
a1


t2
a2



.
.
.
I have drafted the code like this:
data mytable;
set mytable;
by date;
if _N_=1 then x = 2; else x = .;
run;

proc model data=mytable;
parm beta .5; (->here I set an inital guess value of beta)
bounds 0<=beta<=1;
x = beta*lag(x) + (1-beta)*a;
fit x / outest=beta_results;
run;

There must be some problem with the code as error is:

ERROR: At OLS Iteration 0 there are 0 nonmissing observations available. At least 1 are needed to compute the next iteration.

I also found that some would suggest using PROC NLIN command, but honestly I am not sure how to set up codes using this package. I hope the information above make sense.
Thanks!
Yumi

Can you post some sample data with values that we can use? I am wondering if you can  alternatively achieve this with the %AR() macro.
